# JShell throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException on startup

Tags: java, linux, debian, jshell

I'm trying to start a jshell on Debian 10 buster. I've downloaded jdk-16_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz from Oracle and unpacked it into 'jdk-16' in my home directory. I've set the PATH and JAVA_HOME:

```
~$ export PATH=~/jdk-16/bin:$PATH
~$ export JAVA_HOME=~/jdk-16
~$ javac --version
javac 16
~$ java --version
java 16 2021-03-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16+36-2231)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16+36-2231, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Test "Hello world" program can be successfully compiled and run in this environment. However, when I'm trying to run jshell I got the following error:

```
~$ jshell
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 16
|  For an introduction type: /help intro
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOError: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5
    at jdk.internal.le/jdk.internal.org.jline.utils.Curses.tputs(Curses.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.le/jdk.internal.org.jline.utils.Curses.tputs(Curses.java:45)
    at jdk.internal.le/jdk.internal.org.jline.keymap.KeyMap.key(KeyMap.java:243)
    at jdk.internal.le/jdk.internal.org.jline.reader.impl.LineReaderImpl.key(LineReaderImpl.java:6095)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
    at jdk.internal.le/jdk.internal.org.jline.reader.impl.LineReaderImpl.bindKeys(LineReaderImpl.java:6103)
    at jdk.internal.le/jdk.internal.org.jline.reader.impl.LineReaderImpl.emacs(LineReaderImpl.java:5813)
    at jdk.internal.le/jdk.internal.org.jline.reader.impl.LineReaderImpl.defaultKeyMaps(LineReaderImpl.java:5789)
    at jdk.internal.le/jdk.internal.org.jline.reader.impl.LineReaderImpl.<init>(LineReaderImpl.java:293)
    at jdk.jshell/jdk.internal.jshell.tool.ConsoleIOContext$2.<init>(ConsoleIOContext.java:133)
    at jdk.jshell/jdk.internal.jshell.tool.ConsoleIOContext.<init>(ConsoleIOContext.java:133)
    at jdk.jshell/jdk.internal.jshell.tool.JShellTool.start(JShellTool.java:978)
    at jdk.jshell/jdk.internal.jshell.tool.JShellToolBuilder.start(JShellToolBuilder.java:254)
    at jdk.jshell/jdk.internal.jshell.tool.JShellToolProvider.main(JShellToolProvider.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:48)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:711)
    at jdk.internal.le/jdk.internal.org.jline.utils.Curses.doTputs(Curses.java:359)
    at jdk.internal.le/jdk.internal.org.jline.utils.Curses.tputs(Curses.java:60)
    ... 21 more
```

I've also tried jdk-15.0.2 with the same result. There is also Java 8 JDK installed in ~/jdk8, but I don't think there is any interference between the different versions, because PATH and JAVA_HOME are set correctly. What can be the reason of this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason was that curses library could not correctly initialize, because I had an "unusual" terminal settings (I'm using rxvt-unicode-256color). The following setting

```
$ export TERM=xterm
```

has fixed the error.

Comment: TERM=rxvt causes the issue as well. Very "unusual" indeed :)